# Trying To Get A Button Working With a TextField iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

So I am starting to learn Swift and iOS and just working through simple tasks. One is adding a Label to display text, a textfield for input and a button to change the Label to display the text.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var myTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


    // MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func changeLabel(sender: UIButton) {

        if textField.text != "" {
        myTitle.text = textField.text
        textField.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

The weird thing is it works once (when you hit the button the title changes to the text in the textfield) but when I hit the button again I get the following error:

> 2016-05-21 15:32:28.160 labelTextField[80764:36875633] -[UIButton text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe8a8d50ff0
>   2016-05-21 15:32:28.166 labelTextField[80764:36875633] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe8a8d50ff0'

Since it works once I'm not really sure what changes the second time I hit the button.

Comment: You changed names of a connector from storyboard - `labelTextField` is calling for a selector that doesn't exist in your class. Right click on the control in the storyboard and remove that reference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have an if statement just put

```
myTitle.text = textField.text
```

instead of

```
if textField.text != "" {
    myTitle.text = textField.text
    textField.text = ""
}
```